# Is it possible to create a top-level test run configuration in Intelij IDEA so that all my JUnit tests run with it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I've got a bunch of Selenium tests in my project and I'd love running them with IDEA. I need to pass certain VM arguments (where my firefox binary is located etc.) and I don't want to create a run config for every Test class that I have.

There are also too many tests to just run all every time.

So, does anyone know if it's possible to create a "parent" run config which would be used for all tests in a certain path whether I run them together or just a single one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I feel silly :P

`Run Configurations` has a `Defaults` tab where you can set default values for JUnit tasks